# How do I find current root logins

Tags: login, root, kill

How can I identify all terminals that have a root login on them on Linux?

`who -a` seems to give me regular logins but what about root?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `who` command (and the `w` command for that matter) also shows root logins, but if someone logged in as a normal user and eleveted his/her rights with `su`/`sudo` than it won't show it since the login hasn't really changed.

So in that case you are probably better off looking for `su`, `sudo` or `/bin/bash` (or whatever the shell) processes.

I would guess that something like this should work for you:

```
ps aux | grep -E '/bin/zsh|/bin/bash'
```

Although you probably want to look at `/etc/shells` instead of hardcoding the shells.

Comment: Additionally, have a look through /var/log/secure, which should identify su's to root and others.

Answer (score 2):

Use `w` to see who is logged on:

```
w | grep root
```

Comment: `who` (with no additional options) should also list terminals where root is logged in...